# Unable to find name traits error - adobe air for ios

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, adobe

I get this error when I try to package the app. Any help on this one?

I'm using pure AS3 with latest Adobe Air 14 sdk.

> Failed to package AIR application neginaMobile.ipa:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unable to find named traits: fl.managers::e at adobe.abc.Domain.resolveTypeName(Domain.java:232) at adobe.abc.Domain.resolveTypeName(Domain.java:149) at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer.sccp_eval(GlobalOptimizer.java:6775) at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer$SccpContext.commit(GlobalOptimizer.java:4448) at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer.sccp_modify(GlobalOptimizer.java:5919) at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer.sccp_modify(GlobalOptimizer.java:4781) at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer.sccp(GlobalOptimizer.java:4753) at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer.optimize(GlobalOptimizer.java:3615) at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer.optimize(GlobalOptimizer.java:2309) at adobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.optimizeABCs(LLVMEmitter.java:534) at adobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.generateBitcode(LLVMEmitter.java:343) at com.adobe.air.ipa.GOAOTCompiler.convertAbcToLlvmBitcodeImpl(GOAOTCompiler.java:243) at com.adobe.air.ipa.BitcodeGenerator.main(BitcodeGenerator.java:85) Compilation failed while executing : ADT

Answer (score 0):

[A quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Failed+to+package+AIR+application+Exception+in+thread+"main"+java.lang.Error:+Unable+to+find+named+traits) turned up [this Adobe post of common errors](http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/06/11/common-issues-faced-in-developing-native-extensions-for-air-on-ios/). It includes the exception you're seeing and says the following:

> b. Sometimes, you may encounter an error of the type:
>
> > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unable to find named traits: com.open::Screen
> >     at adobe.abc.Domain.resolveTypeName(Domain.java:231)
> >     at adobe.abc.Domain.resolveTypeName(Domain.java:148)
> >     at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer$InputAbc.resolveTypeName(GlobalOptimizer.java:272)
> >     Compilation failed while executing : ADT
>
> This is probably because you have not included the extension in your application.xml. To fix it, add the extensionID of your application in your application descriptor.